# how to check if some one connected to the boost::interprocess::message_queue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I have a `boost::interprocess::message_queue` that connects two processes, is there a way to know if the two processes are alive and connected?
My current method is to send HartBeat messages and if I'm not getting a response after x mill I'm raising the error.
is there a way to use the `boost::interprocess::message_queue` API to check this?

Comment: I don't think so but you could perhaps use a `boost::interprocess::basic_managed_shared_memory` for each `message_queue` and store connected process id:s in it. Checking if a process stored in the shared memory is alive can probably be done with another `boost` function, or you could use native functions to do that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo So, that means you cannot do what OP asked

Comment: Non-portable methods exist. For example `fuser` or `lsof` can list programs using `/dev/shm/my-message-queue`

Comment: @sehe I don't think so. I didn't see it in the documentation, but I did find the `interprocess::basic_managed_shared_memory` there which perhaps could provide a workaround.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Interprocess is geared to interprocess comms. A lot of mechanisms can be used to signal "in-use". I'd say [sharable mutex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.sharable_upgradable_mutexes.upgradable_whats_a_mutex) or [semaphore](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores) make a little bit more sense.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the lock types internal to `managed_shared_memory` are non-robust, meaning that abnormal process termination will lead to stuck locks.

Comment: @sehe I see. Perhaps not my best guesstion ever then :-)

Comment: @sehe and Ted Lyngmo thank you both for your input - I guess I'll stick with the Hart Beat method :)